# What are the serious uses of returning the this pointer from a function?

Tags: c++, pointers, this

Following is a fancy code:

```
class B
{
    private:
        int sum;

    public:
        B ()
        {
            sum = 0;
        }

        B& add (int number)
        {
            sum =+ number;
            return *this;
        }
};

int main ()
{
    B obj;
    obj.add (1).add (2).add (3). add (4);
}
```

Fine, what are the "serious" uses of returning the this pointer from a function call?

Comment: What really is serious is that you are returning `*this` from a function declared to return `void` :-)

Comment: Operators will often return a reference to the object in question, to allow chaining, so `return *this`. Much as in your example. This *is* a "serious" use.

Comment: @hochl That's dumb of me, will correct the code.

Comment: @hochl Does that make sense now?

Comment: If you declare it as `B& add( ... )` then yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example would be;

```
class basic_ostream
    : ...
{
    basic_ostream& operator<<(bool n);
```

You *really* want to return this to be able to chain to;

```
std::cout << boolValue << std::endl;
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `basic_ostream& operator<<(basic_ostream& osr, bool n)` ?

Comment: If you are creating an `operator<<` for your own class, yes, as it won't be a member function. But for the standard ones it is probably a member function, so a relevant example.

Comment: @hochl It's a member of basic_ostream actually, added a skeleton class header to clarify.

Comment: "The defense rests, your honor."

Answer (score 2):

```
mycode $ fgrep -r 'return *this' /usr/include/c++/4.4.3 | wc -l
592
mycode $
```

Comment: @Anisha: the point is that there are 592 uses of `return *this` in GCC's library headers. Presumably all or most of these are "serious", so you can look at any of them for examples.

Answer (score 2):

One use of this is for the [Named Parameter Idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2700976/10077). It depends on method chaining.

```
class Person;

class PersonOptions
{
  friend class Person;
  string name_;
  int age_;
  char gender_;

public:
   PersonOptions() 
   : age_(0), gender_('U')
   {}

   PersonOptions& name(const string& n) { name_ = n; return *this; }
   PersonOptions& age(int a) { age_ = a; return *this; }
   PersonOptions& gender(char g) { gender_ = g; return *this; }
};

class Person
{
  string name_;
  int age_;
  char gender_;

public:
   Person(const PersonOptions& opts) 
   : name_(opts.name_), age_(opts.age_), gender_(opts.gender_)
   {}
};
Person p = PersonOptions().name("George").age(57).gender('M');
Person p = PersonOptions().age(25).name("Anna");
```

Comment: @MooingDuck: Thanks for covering my laziness. ;v)

Comment: middle click, CTRL+C, select this tab, CTRL+V?

Answer (score 1):

The initial reason wass for chaining mathematical operations, like this:

```
class mynumberclass {
    int internal;
public:
    mynumberclass(int);
    mynumberclass operator+(const mynumberclass&) const;
    mynumberclass operator-(const mynumberclass&) const;
    mynumberclass operator*(const mynumberclass&) const;
    mynumberclass operator/(const mynumberclass&) const;
    mynumberclass operator%(const mynumberclass&) const;
    mynumberclass& operator+=(const mynumberclass&);
    mynumberclass& operator-=(const mynumberclass&);
    mynumberclass& operator*=(const mynumberclass&);
    mynumberclass& operator/=(const mynumberclass&);
    mynumberclass& operator%=(const mynumberclass&);
};

int main() {
    mynumberclass a(3);
    mynumberclass b(4);
    mynumberclass c = (a * b + b) / 2; //this chains 3 of the above operators
}
```

without chaining, that code would have to look like this:

```
int main() {
    mynumberclass a(3);
    mynumberclass b(4);
    mynumberclass c(a);
    c *= b;
    c += b;
    c /= 2;
}
```

FredLarson also mentions the Named Parameter Idiom, which is certainly an awesome thing you can use chaining for.

Comment: You for sure don't want dyadic operators modifying their left operand. You return by value from them.

Comment: @AProgrammer: Never seen the word "dyadic" before, but I realized what you meant anyway.  Fixed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is chaining functions to perform operations on the same object. jQuery, although not C++, has shown that this can be a very useful paradigm.