# C++ multiple sets of parameters with their own parentheses on function call?

Tags: c++, function

I've been coding in C/C++ for a while and I'm using the https://github.com/jarro2783/cxxopts library. The library uses the *add_options()* function to grab it's configuration, like this:

```
options.add_options() ("option1", "Description1") ("option2", "Description2");
```

And you can add an arbitrary number of options.

It came as a surprise that this is valid C/C++ and works; I have never seen something like that.

How are they doing it? Is there a name for this syntax?

Comment: Looked at the source yet?

Comment: Overloading the [function call operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) and chaining.

Comment: This is likely done by using a type that has `operator()` which returns an instance of the same type.

Comment: This is some dark magic, and I'm not sure if I should be impressed or terrified. This is like what some people do with JavaScript functions where they add functions to the functions...

Comment: @ulrich-eckhardt of course looking at the source code was the first thing I did, but there was a possibility that this was a new feature of some C++ version I didn't know about (first thing I googled).

I've been doing C/C++ for 3 years on a daily basis (an a lot of industrial experience before that), no need to bash my question as me being lazy, I truly want to learn how to do this for my own code.

Comment: Actually a variant of the [Named Parameter Idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2700976/10077), it appears.

Comment: You may want to program in C or C++.  Switching between the two can get very annoying sometimes and besides, there is no C/C++ language.  For example, in C you don't have member functions and you can't overload functions or operators.

Comment: @thomas-matthews You're right on that, but I usually just need some behaviors from C regarding memory. I deal with enough data to easily fill my RAM (computer vision) and sometmes it's just safer for me to use pointers instead of references. I use C++ as much as I can though, C when C++ is too safe for my own speed needs.

Comment: @DanyAlejandro, there are many lazy people here that want to be fed information that they are too lazy to locate themselves. Your question honestly seems like one, simply because you include a link to the source but no indication that you investigated there. Anyhow, good that you got answers. BTW: There's another way you could have found out how this works, you could have stepped through it with a debugger. If you don't know how to use one, you're missing one of the most important tools for a programmer.

Comment: @ulrich-eckhardt Thanks for the tip, I know how to use a debugger, and I decided to ask the developer community instead; they know things a debugger cannot teach me and the question was worth it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`options.add_options()` returns an object.

That object has the function call operator overload that takes two strings, which most likely looks like

```
ObjectType& operator()(std::string const& option, std::string const& value);
```

which allows you to chain the function calls.

Here's a simple program that demonstrates the concept.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
   Foo& operator()(int x)
   {
      std::cout << "Got " << x << std::endl;
      return *this;
   }
};

struct Bar
{
   Foo getFoo() { return Foo(); }
};


int main()
{
   Bar b;
   b.getFoo()(10)(200)(30);
}
```

Output of the program:

```
Got 10
Got 200
Got 30
```

That line in `main` is equivalent to:

```
Foo foo = b.getFoo();
foo(10);
foo(200);
foo(30);
```

---

**PS**

Personally, I find that style of coding a bit cryptic and best avoided. I would rather see:

```
auto& option = options.add_options();
option.addOption("option1", "Description1");
option.addOption("option2", "Description2");
```

That's a lot clearer to understand, IMO.

Comment: Amazing, will definitely use this in the future!

Comment: @DanyAlejandro Even though I understand the syntax, i don't encourage such coding style.

Comment: Yes, I recognized this style from using JSON objects to set-up function calls in JavaScript, which is very practical, and that's what made me so excited. But other C++ programmers probably don't agree, and I don't want to force people to google to read my code.